# Lesbegue covering lemma. What is the conclusion?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

In this [proof](https://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/naik/classes/741/lebesgue.pdf) I am reading

I am to understand that for every $i$, we really want to show that $r$, in particular,  equals the $\inf \{ d(x,y): x \in U_i, x \in A_i\}$ for that $i$ and this will give us $B(x,r) \subset U$.

1) Why are we considering $f(x)$, the maximum of all $f_i$?

2) The proof concludes $r$ being the minimum is the contradiction, so the assumption $y \notin U_i$ is wrong? And how does that prove $r := \inf \{d(x,y) \}$

Answer (score 1):

1. For each $x\in X$ and each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $f_i(x)$ is the distance from $x$ to $X\setminus U_i$. Therefore, $f_i(x)>0$ means that $x$ is inside $U_i$. If $f=\max\bigl\{f_i\,|\,i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\bigr\}$, asserting that $f(x)>0$ means that $x$ is inside *some* $U_i$.
2. No, the proof does *not* conclude that “$r$ being the minimum is the contradiction”. In the proof, $r$ is *defined* as the minimum of $f$. Then the author proves that, for each $x\in X$,$$B(x,r)\subset U_i,\tag{1}$$for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. In order to do that, the author chooses $i$ such that $f(x)=f_i(x)$ and then shows that if we hadn't $(1)$, then we would get a contradiction.

Comment: 1. So then why don't we consider $\min$?

Comment: @Hawk Because that could be the null function. Suppose that $X=\{0,1\}$, that $U_0=\{0\}$, and that $U_1=\{1\}$,